# Huge number of open, unanswered low-quality questions

Tags: discussion

I just recently joined this site. There are a lot of posts that are low-quality or off-topic which haven't been moderated. I'm trying to flag new ones. Do we have moderators here? Are they active? I'm happy to wade back through the old posts and help get this site cleaned up a little bit.

This thread goes back a little and mentions my concern in an answer: [3 Years now, is an end to Beta in sight?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/3-years-now-is-an-end-to-beta-in-sight/283#283)

Has there already been a discussion about the minimum requirements to keep a question from being closed? There are many questions that don't include vehicle information. There are many where the user did not return to provide it.

What kind of questions are on-topic? Is this a place for vehicle owners to inquire about maintenance prices and service schedules or is this a place for professional and hobby mechanics to ask questions about servicing their vehicles?

Comment: If you haven't been around in a bit there has been a huge effort to remediate the very issue you address in this post.  Additionally there have been quite a few other 'changes'.  You should come by and look around.  It's much better.  Our traffic has almost doubled to and the QPD is soaring as well as a much more active mid tier community of voters.

Answer (score 3):

> ... or is this a place for professional and hobby mechanics to ask questions about servicing their vehicles?

This is how it should be. There is *some* bit of crossover into some areas which are close to being off topic. Price quoting and shopping assistance are *definitely* off topic. I think the [question from today on whether the guy is getting gouged](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18767/is-it-reasonable-to-charge-the-customer-1000-to-assemble-the-top-of-the-engine) is *very close* to being off topic.

Yes, two of the three mods are active, but remember, SE sites are self governing. The patrons make most of the decisions. The mods are here to clean up after us and solve the "people issues".

A good place to understand what has been hashed out here in Meta is through the [scope tag](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope).

(I've got more I could throw in here, but I'll let you ask followup questions after you have read some of the scope questions.)

Comment: Yeah, I think I flagged that one honestly. He had a lot to say and I feel that  Q&A format questions need to be pointed (more or less) in order to have a good answer.

Comment: Sometimes we just *aren't going to get a good answer*, so must just do the best we can do. I've been trying to do this with older, non-answered questions lately. Just trying to ensure there is an answer to a question. Sometimes they are good answers. Other times they are adequate answers. I've also noticed I've put a lot of *comments* to questions, which I've been trying to convert over to answers. Sometimes that's a direct copy. Other times it's an educated guess to flesh out the comment a little better and make a coherent answer to it. Great fun.